# Embeddable CMS for .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, content-management-system, editor

Can you recommend a CMS framework that could be **embedded** into **existing** web application?

The requirements are:

- Users can go nuts and customise it to their liking.
- User friendly and easy to use.
- Should support multitenancy (users have their own sites).
- Should support multiple subdomains (so file uploads and stuff should not be mixed up).
- Use existing (very) custom authentication and authorisation system.
- Should be part of the application so that it is easy to share the same database and data structures.
- Should be easily unit-testable.

Thanks.

Comment: So, you are looking for the perfect CMS that does everything just about any CMS invented can't do and you can drop it into your existing solution . . .

Comment: @Wyatt not looking for CMS that does everything. Most of usual stuff. But primarily I should be able to drop it into my app, yes.

Comment: Maybe my requirements sound to high, but I would love to at least know some of the options.

Comment: Consider SharePoint, which is built on ASP.NET.

Comment: @John, nice joke about SharePoint :) It is a joke, right?

Comment: SharePoint? I'd prefer to keep my hair.

Comment: No, that wasn't a joke, and have you looked at it lately? Especially the SharePoint Foundation 2010 which is _free_ with a Windows Server license?

Comment: SharePoint is very unusable and it is not only a CMS system. It's a bloated app that tries to do everything and definitely is not suitable as a CMS for end-customers publishing content on the web. Just over-complicated from many perspectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that Orchard was as close as you can get in .NET.

Unfortunately it sounds good in theory but showed itself bad in practice.

The answer to the questions - **there is none**.

You would be better of using an external one or just roll your own with small feature sets.

Neither solution is perfect and should be considered on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: For a lightweight option you can checkout Mr.CMS

Answer (score 1):

I would say CMS is not supposed to be used as an embedded into existing web applicaton. In this case I would suggest to find not CMS, but some third-party components that will do everything for you: [EntLib](http://entlib.codeplex.com/) for User Authentication, [Yahoo UI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) for User Experience, and so on.

In other way take a look at [Orchard Project](http://orchardproject.net/) by Microsoft - it's free, open source, well structured and organized (modules, ui customization, IoC, etc.), and well community supported CMS.

If your web application is made with ASP.NET MVC then it will not be hard to make 'a Bridge' between Orchard CMS API and your web application -- Model, Business Logic, Controllers ("Drivers" in terms of Orchard), etc. as Orchard Modules.

Comment: Whether CMS is supposed or not to be embedded, we **need to provide that functionality** for the customers. That's being said. EntLib, YUI etc have **nothing to do with fully blown CMS**. Orchards is a bit too bloated (it feels like well done DNN). But the biggest problem with it is that it doesn't seem to support **multitenancy** which is critical.

Comment: @Dmytrii Nagirniak - Orchard supports Multitenancy, you have to enable it in modules though.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I realised it after I posted the comment. There are certain things that are not supported that I need (install theme per tenant for example). But so far it looks like Orchard is the only more or less good "embeddable" CMS.